# javascript: can i avoid eval in this example?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

I have to deal with a customers Javascript Framework for a very specific task.

I have this html:

```
<div data-foo="(#a = #b)">...loading</div>
```

In Javascript I get the `data-*`-Attribute as a string:

```
foo = '(#a = #b)'
```

then an ajax call is made with the following answer:

```
#a=1, #b=1
```

next the tags are replaced with the values from ajax call (and the operator is replaced as well):

```
foo = '(1 == 1)'
```

then `foo` is evaluated with eval();

```
result = eval(foo)  // true
```

Is there a way to avoid `eval()`? I always have to evaluate string like `'(0 == 1)'` or `'((0 == 0) && (1 == 0))'`. I have no chance to influence servers resonse. I need a good and safe way to evaluate the strings to `true` or `false`.

**EDIT:**

possible strings are:

```
'(0 == 0)'
'(0 == 1)'
'(0 > 5)'
'(117 > 0)'
'((0 == 1) && (11 == 11))'
'((0 == 1) || (0 == 0))'
'(((0 < 1) || (0 == 0) ) && (33 != 11))'
...and so on!
```

the result always need to be `true` or `false`.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but 1) what are the possible strings ? 2) why do you want to avoid eval ?

Comment: The real question is why `eval` was used in the first place. This program flow smells something awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some resources that might solve your problem:

- http://mathjs.org/
- http://jsep.from.so/
- http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/

There are many more out there. Search "[javascript expression parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20expression%20parser)".

Comment: those expression parsers are to heavy for my application. Can someone suggest a lightweight expression parser for the strings I posted above?